# How to check the effect of a treatment when you do not have control group?

Tags: econometrics, difference-in-difference, propensity-scores

I have a facebook dataset ranging from January-2010 to May-2017 in which the focus of my study are the columns including categories (Group A & Group B), Timestamp, Engagement (Sum of likes, comments and shares on each post). Facebook updates/tweaks their algorithm over the years.

I am focusing on this particular tweak implemented in August-2014, and I want to test how this change in algorithm effected the engagement (increased/decreased) of both groups. In particular, I am trying to check before and after (1 year for both) engagement and draw a comparison between both groups and justify which group did better.

Since I have before and after data and both groups correspond to treatment group, I do not have any control group so I belive I cannot use DiD and Propensity Score Matching.

My question is, what sort of test should I apply to check the effects of that tweak?

Comment: PS methods compare the outcomes between two groups; the labels "treated" and "control" are just labels used in the literature to make it easy for those who understand experiments to understand the methods. If you want to compare engagement between two treatments, all the standard causal inference methods are applicable. You don't actually have to a treated group and a control group.